# What is the best way to resolve the error "Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints"?

Tags: ios, swift, debugging

I imagine most projects don't have just one or two stack views with constraints, so.... 
How can I use the information provided in this error report to trace down exactly which constraint(s) in my project is problematic? In a project with potentially hundreds of constraints, how can I know which 2 constraints are being problematic in this case?

```
2020-03-22 14:31:59.690493-0400 Splittr[39203:4533416] [LayoutConstraints] Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
    Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. 
    Try this: 
        (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; 
        (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. 
(
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x600001eff0c0 H:|-(4)-[UIStackView:0x7fa5ec678e30]   (active, names: '|':UIStackView:0x7fa5ec601960 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x600001ec8500 'UISV-canvas-connection' UIStackView:0x7fa5ec601960.leading == UIStackView:0x7fa5ec678e30.leading   (active)>"
)

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x600001ec8500 'UISV-canvas-connection' UIStackView:0x7fa5ec601960.leading == UIStackView:0x7fa5ec678e30.leading   (active)>

Make a symbolic breakpoint at UIViewAlertForUnsatisfiableConstraints to catch this in the debugger.
The methods in the UIConstraintBasedLayoutDebugging category on UIView listed in <UIKitCore/UIView.h> may also be helpful.
```

Answer (score 0):

> In a project with potentially hundreds of constraints, how can I know which 2 constraints are being problematic in this case?

**TIP ONE** Look in the View Debugger. The constraints with the conflicts should usually be clearly shown with exclamation marks.

**TIP TWO** Give all your constraints identifier strings. You can do that in the storyboard or (if you create the constraints in code) in code. That way, the name appears in the conflicting constraints report and you know instantly which constraint is which.

(Unfortunately, constraints generated by the stack view will not have identifiers and you can't add them. But you will at least know that they they come from the stack view.)

**TIP THREE** Another really good trick is to give all your views names. For example, you could give your stack views names and then you can work out which one is which. I do that by assigning to string to the view's `layer.name`; most people don't know that a `layer` has a `name` property that is just sitting there doing nothing.

Comment: It might seem like overkill now, and a big pain to go back thru all your views and constraints and give them names, but as you can see, you'll be a lot happier when there's a conflict and you need to track it down.